# Python: renaming method names on-the-fly

Tags: python, dynamic, decorator

I have many files using classes with the following syntax:

```
o = module.CreateObject()
a = o.get_Field
```

and now the implementation has changed from 'get_XXX' and 'set_XXX' to just 'XXX':

```
o = module.CreateObject()
a = o.Field
```

This implementation is an external package, which I don't want to change. Is it possible to write a wrapper which will on-the-fly intercept all calls to 'get_XXX' and replace then with calls to the new name 'XXX'?

```
o = MyRenamer(module.CreateObject())
a = o.get_Field   # works as before, o.Field is called
a = o.DoIt()      # works as before, o.DoIt is called
```

It needs to intercept all calls, not just to a finite-set of fields, decide based on the method name if to modify it and cause a method with a modified name to be called.

Comment: o.get_Field = o.Field, you can make them make a new wrapper class for this.

Comment: You can do that, but you will still probably need to change your use of `set_xxx` function, because `o.set_field(val)` will now become `o.field = val` --- that is, not just the name but the syntax will change.

Comment: Were `.get_Field()` and `.set_Field()` perhaps *methods*? Did you have to call these to get the value, and pass in a new value to set them? E.g. `o.set_Field('new value')`?

Comment: [theAlse]: I'd like to overrride any field name, thus not do it one-by-one.

Comment: [Martijn Pieters]: yes, get_Field and set_Field were methods

Comment: Ah, if `get_Field` and `set_Field` methods got rolled into a single `Field` property, then just wrapping attribute access won't be enough. You also need to make them callable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to continue to use `get_Field` and `set_Field` on an object that has switched to using properties (where you simply access or assign to `Field`), it's possible to use an wrapper object:

```
class NoPropertyAdaptor(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name.startswith("get_"):
            return lambda: getattr(self.obj, name[4:])
        elif name.startswith("set_"):
            return lambda value: setattr(self.obj, name[4:], value)
        else:
            return getattr(self.obj, name)
```

This will have problems if you are using extra syntax, like indexing or iteration on the object, or if you need to recognize the type of the object using `isinstance`.

A more sophisticated solution would be to create a subclass that does the name rewriting and force the object to use it. This isn't exactly a wrapping, since outside code will still deal with the object directly (and so magic methods and `isinstance`) will work as expected. This approach will work for most objects, but it might fail for types that have fancy metaclass magic going on and for some builtin types:

```
def no_property_adaptor(obj):
    class wrapper(obj.__class__):
        def __getattr__(self, name):
            if name.startswith("get_"):
                return lambda: getattr(self, name[4:])
            elif name.startswith("set_"):
                return lambda value: setattr(self, name[4:], value)
            else:
                return super(wrapper, self).__getattr__(name)

    obj.__class__ = wrapper
    return obj
```

Comment: There are many disadvantages to using a wrapper, including breaking APIs that internally use `isinstance()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, the simple code above is really only good if you're doing fairly limited work with the wrapped object (such as only accessing attributes and methods). It is possible to wrap more complicated behavior (for instance, by creating a subclass and changing the wrapped object's `__class___` to it), but this can be overkill in situations where the complicated behavior is not used.

Comment: You *really* don't want to change the `__class__`, not when you can [already hook into `isinstance()` tests](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks). My point is that wrappers can get complicated, fast.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm not sure that `__instancecheck__` will help when writing a wrapper, since it would need to be implemented in the metaclass of the type you're checking against (which is the original type of obj). You can't add it to the wrapper type! See my updated answer for an implementation that creates a one-off subclass and hacks the `__class__` property of the object to use it.

Comment: Ick, you are of course correct. I need my caffeine still this morning.

Answer (score 2):

You can ['monkey patch'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) any python class; import the class directly and add a property:

```
import original_module

@property
def get_Field(self):
    return self.Field

original_module.OriginalClass.get_Field = get_Field
```

You'd need to enumerate what fields you wanted to access this way:

```
def addField(fieldname, class):
    @property
    def get_Field(self):
        return getattr(self, fieldname)

    setattr(original_module.OriginalClass, 'get_{}'.format(fieldname), get_Field)

for fieldname in ('Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'):
    addField(fieldname, original_module.OriginalClass)
```